# Java: What does the first index represent in 2D array?

Tags: java, arrays

In java, say for example I have `char[][] board`, what does `board.length` and `board[0].length` represent? Is `board.length` the length of the x axis and y axis for the `board[0].length`?

Thank you

Comment: `board.length` is the "length" of the first dimension (how many arrays there are in the array) and `board[0].length` is the "length" of the "second" dimension (how many elements are in the first array). X and Y could be interpretations for these values

Comment: @UnholySheep so X axis for `board.length` and Y axis for `board[0].length`?

Comment: @LyManeug X and Y exist only in the eye of the beholder, you can track them on either dimension of your 2D array.

Comment: If you want to interpret it that way. The dimensions themselves have no "meaning". It's up to you to decide how you use them

Comment: I think that 2D array is like a box of storage, like if you give a heigth of 5 and a width of 4, you will have a dimensional array that has a  area of 20.

Comment: @msagala a (1D) array is like a box of storage; a "2D" array is a box of storage storing boxes of storage. There's nothing really two-dimensional about it though, and there's no sense of "width" and "height".

Comment: I know It has nothing to do with heigth and width. I'm just explaining that it is like that you are building a storage like in a dimension it will look like a square.

Comment: there is no such thing as 2D array in Java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A 2-dimensional array has no intrinsic notion of "x" and "y", or "width" and "height". A 2-dimensional array doesn't even really have the notion of being 2-dimensional: it is a 1-dimensional array of "things", where each of those things is a 1-dimensional array.

[image]

So a `char[][]` is a 1-dimensional array where every element is a `char[]`; and every `char[]` is a 1-dimensional array where every element is a `char`. Notice that there's not even a requirement for the contained arrays to be of the same length as each other.

As such, you can't ask "Is board.length the length of the x axis and y axis for the board[0].length?": they represent that if that's how you choose to construct and interpret your array.

Consider constructing an array like this:

```
char[][] board = new char[3][4];
```

This makes a 2-dimensional array, where all of the 3 sub-arrays have length 4.

Applying your description, it can be visually represented like this:

[image]

So here, the `i` in `[i][j]` represents the x-coordinate, and the `j` represents the y-coordinate. Hence, `board.length` would be the x size, and `board[0].length` would be the y size.

But here's another way of interpreting the same 2-dimensional array, where the x- and y-axes are transposed.

[image]

Now, the `i` in `[i][j]` represents the y-coordinate, and the `j` represents the x-coordinate. Hence, `board.length` would be the y size, and `board[0].length` would be the x size.

Neither is right, neither is wrong. It depends upon what you're trying to represent as to which you choose.

Answer (score 3):

You can image the 2D array to this

- board.length     -> rows size
- board[0].length  -> the fist row's columns size

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A two-dimensional array might not have the same length for all the rows. For example, consider this array declaration:

```
int [][]a = {{1,2,3},{1,2},{1,2,3,4,5},{1,2,3,4}};
```

This image explains exactly what the a[i].length is:

[image]

whereas `a.length` is the number of rows of the array (in this case 4).

Answer (score 1):

2D array is like this.

```
int[][] twoDArray = new int[3][3];
```

> [0,0] [0,1] [0,2] 
>  
>   [1,0] [1,1] [1,2] 
>   [2,0] [2,1] [2,2]

`twoDArray.length` is like a row.
`twoDArray[0].length` is like a column.

Answer (score 0):

By way of example:

```
char[][] board = new char[10][5];
System.out.println(board.length);     // prints 10
System.out.println(board[0].length);  // prints 5
```

The length of the array itself is the length of the first dimension.  Accessing an element in that first dimension can then reveal what the length of the second dimension is, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Well `board.length` returns the length of your 2D Array while `board[0].length` returns the length of the first Element in your 2D-Array, which is the same for all Arrays stored in `board`. This doesn't neccesseraly have anything to do with x and y-axes, but sure, you could visualize a 2d char Array like this:

```
    [0] [1] [2] [3] [4] [5]
[0]  a   b   c   d   e   f
[1]  g   h   i   f   j   k
[2]  l   m   n   o   p   q
[3]  r   s   t   u   v   w
[4]  x   y   z   A   B   C
```

If you think `board[x]` as the x-axis of the table and `board[x][x]` as the y-axis you'd have `board.length` returning the width / length of x-axis (In this case `5`) and `board[0].length` returning the height / length of y-axis (In this case `4`).